# Getting current month in mmm format with Selenium IDE

Tags: date, selenium, selenium-ide

I've been using the below code to get the **current date** in `"mm dd, yyyy"` format but the web page has changed and now I need to get the info as `"mmm dd, yyyy"` (like "Jun 27, 2012").   Is there a way to reformat the month in the command below or do I need another section of code  to reformat it?

```
<tr>
<td>storeEval </td>
<td>var d=new Date(); ((d.getMonth())) + ' ' + d.getDate() +', '+d.getFullYear();</td>
<td>todayDate</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's not really clear why you created a table in your question - was it meant to represent a table in your actual code?

Comment: That's the raw code in Selenium IDE which is always in tables.

Comment: I suspected that *might* be the case, but in your original post it didn't show up appropriately, and I wasn't sure what you were trying to do...

Answer (score 3):

This is the easiest way I got:

```
var d = new Date().toDateString().split(' '); d[1] + ' ' + d[2] + ', ' +d[3];
```

Documentation on [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and [`toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString).

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3k6ahb3a%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), it also works in IE6+, so there should be no problems in any browser.